# Why does material-ui-lab rating component sometimes send null onChange?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

New to working with material-ui and I'm having an issue with input on @material-ui/lab/Rating. Occasionally, when I try to click on the rating component multiple times in a row, the value passed to my controller comes back as null instead of the rating I clicked on. The following is my console after logging incoming data in my controller:

```
Rating Passed: 5
id:  60a42672c615650cb85629f4
Rating Passed: null
id:  60a42672c615650cb85629f4
Rating Passed: 4
id:  60a42672c615650cb85629f4
```

Snippet from my front-end:

```
<CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
        <Rating name={post._id} value={post.raters !== 0 ? post.rating/post.raters : 0} precision={1} max={5} onChange={(event, v)=>{dispatch(ratePost(post._id , {rating: v}))}}/>
</CardActions>
```

And if it's relevant, my controller:

```
export const ratePost = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("Rating Passed: ", req.body.rating);
        const { id: _id } = req.params;
        console.log("id: ", _id);
        if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(_id)) {
            return res.status(404).send('Post to rate not found');
        }

        const post = await PostMessage.findById(_id);
        let newRaters = post.raters + 1;
        let newRating = (post.rating + req.body.rating);
        if(req.body.rating === null) {
            newRaters = post.raters;
            newRating = post.rating;
        }

        const updatedPost = await PostMessage.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, {rating: newRating, raters: newRaters}, {new:true});
        res.json(updatedPost);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Currently, in my controller I just ignore null inputs. However, it makes the site feel unresponsive when a rating click isn't registered. What could cause the rating component to send a null value?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the StackOveflow. The Rating component seems fine. Can you reproduce your problem online in the sandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2t6i5f
So using the code-sandbox provided on the material-ui docs, it sends null every other time you click without moving the mouse. (I think because it assumes the user is trying to reset their rating and pick something else?) This is not consistent with what's happening in my app (the null and correct values don't alternate nicely and moving the mouse doesn't necessarily help).

If I can't reproduce in the sandbox is there somewhere else in my code I should look to see where this problem might be coming from? Is it something to do with redux?